# php return types or enums?

Tags: php, codeigniter, enums, weblogic, return

I am using ***Codeignitor*** for programming and coming from c#.
its look like a newbie question ,but i want to do something like this.

I have some functions that which return some values :

Example :

```
function Create_db()
{

//do something

      if (PassWordError) //some errors here it is password incorrect
       {
         return "PASS_ERROR";
       }

}
```

and in some places i am using like this

```
$result = Create_db(); //assume that there are some problems and returned "PASS_ERROR"
```

so that the `$result` is string now,

is there anything like ENUMS in php ? or something like that ?

so that i can do something like this :

```
if (passWordError)
{
  return $error->PasswordError();
}
```

i assume that i can have some others types too

like

`Maximum_name_error,authenticationFailedError` etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach to doing this in PHP would be to use class constants:

```
class Something {
    const ERR_HI = 'hi';
    const ERR_FOOBAR = 'foobar';
}


//to use:
return Something::ERR_FOOBAR;
```

Although I would consider using exceptions instead.

Comment: Is the user inputting an invalid password really an exceptional situation if it is something that you can easily do a logic check for?

Comment: Thank you so much ,exceptions are also welcome ,but `const` are more preferable.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry you're right, it does depend on the situation. However, it looked like he had a routine for initializing a DB and assuming you have an invalid password for the configuration, so it looked like you might want to throw in this case.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen what about `define` ? i used the constant.php configuration file on codeignitor ,so that i can use this throughout the site.

Comment: @DileepDil I suppose you could use define as well. I would probably use class constants if the return values are specific to a certain class though, but if you have some kind of shared return values or something then yeah.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to deal with this in CI is to use the Language Class - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Lang file:

```
$lang = array (
'password_error'    =>      'The password you entered is incorrect.',
....
```

)

Controller:

```
   if ($PassWordError) //some errors here it is password incorrect
   {
     return $this->lang->line('password_error');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, when something went wrong, you should throw a custom (or not) exeption and manage it with an exeption handler in your application.

```
if (passWordError)
{
  throw new BadPasswordExeption($params, $you, $need);
}
```

Then you can surround it with a try catch block.

You can find more informations here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: yeah...but the case is different,almost all return's are not exceptions :)